# Confused on when $\mathrm{Img}(T) = \mathbb R^2$ for linear map $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $T: P_2\to \mathbb R^2$ where $T(p) = (p(0), p(1))^\top$ for $p(t) = a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2\in P_2$ a polynomial of degree two. Why is $\mathrm{Img}(T) = \mathbb R^2$?

vs

Given $T': P_2\to \mathbb R^2$ where $T'(p) = (p(0), p(0))^\top$. Why is $\mathrm{Img}(T') \neq \mathbb R^2$ but instead is $\mathrm{Img}(T')  = \{a(1,1)^\top | a\in\mathbb R \}$?

***I am confused on when to say that the image spans the whole space and when it does not. Also, how to find that mathematically without having a matrix to do gauss-jordan on?***

Comment: one criterion: if a generating set of $\mathbb R^2$ lies in the image, $\mathbb R^2$ is already the image. Try to describe the elements in the image! Try to find preimages of generating vectors of $\mathbb R^2$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $p(t) = a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2$

With this you have $p(0)=a_0$ and $p(1)=a_0 + a_1 + a_2$. This means that with the images of the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}p(0)\\p(1)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_0 + a_1 + a_2\end{bmatrix}$$
you can make any $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^2$; it suffices to take $a_0=x$ and, for example, $a_2=-a_0$ and $a_1=y$.

Can you see how this differs from the second situation?

Comment: Oh thank you, I get it now.